# Is there a more proper way to wait for an async function with inner awaits than this?

Tags: javascript, async-await

In the below forEach(), each iteration calls fetch() prefaced with "await".

But the entire function in which this occurs is itself async, so it will execute, kick off the async/await calls, and exit the loop almost immediately.

Before displaying the confirmation dialog at the bottom, I've wrapped it with a setTimeout() to give the inner async/await calls time to finish before displaying the dialog.

This seems fishy to me.  The delay is arbitrary and not guaranteed to be enough time.  I suspect there is a more "standards compliant" way to do this that will deterministically wait until everything is done, but I do not know what it is.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".depts").forEach(async(dept) => {

    let posted = await fetch("API/data/SaveDepartments.ashx",
        {
            //REQUEST BODY
        }
    );

})


setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("op-completed").style.display = "inline";
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert the `.forEach` to a `.map` and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await them all.

```js
const promises = [...document.querySelectorAll(".depts")].map((dept) => {
  return fetch("API/data/SaveDepartments.ashx", {
    //REQUEST BODY
  });
})

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  document.getElementById("op-completed").style.display = "";
})
```

---

Or depending on if you want to do something in each iteration with the returned data, you can use

```js
const promises = [...document.querySelectorAll(".depts")].map(async (dept) => {
  let posted = await fetch("API/data/SaveDepartments.ashx", {
    //REQUEST BODY
  });
  // do whatever with posted
})

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  document.getElementById("op-completed").style.display = "";
})
```

Comment: Instead of removing the `async`/`await` (maybe the OP wants to do more async things there!), I'd recommend keeping the inner function as it was. `Promise.all` with `map` works the same either way because `async` functions return promises (from the outside perspective).

Comment: @CherryDT good point. Added an update to the answer.